# OpenLayers 3: keep sketch after measuring

Tags: openlayers, digitizing, measurements

I followed the official [OpenLayers 3 Measure](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html) example to implement measuring in an application.

It works fine, but when I finish my sketch by double-clicking it dissappears. In the following screenshot you can see the result of the code:

[image]

This is what it looks like during drawing (i.e., measuring). When I double-click to finish the measurment the line appears. However I would like to retain that line (and have the current one only dissapear when I start a new sketch or end the measuring mode, but that is not part of this question, only mentioning it).

Here is my code:

```
var sketch;
var measureTooltipElement;
var measureTooltip;
var drawingForMeasureInteraction;

var formatLength = function(line) {
    var length;
    length = Math.round(line.getLength() * 100) / 100;

    var output;
    if (length > 100) {
        output = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
            ' ' + 'km';
    } else {
        output = (Math.round(length * 100) / 100) +
            ' ' + 'm';
    }
    return output;
};

var formatArea = function(polygon) {
    var area;
    area = polygon.getArea();
    var output;
    if (area > 10000) {
        output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
            ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
    } else {
        output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
            ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
    }
    return output;
};

var measureDrawingCollection = new ol.Collection();

var sourceForMeasureDrawing = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: measureDrawingCollection
});

function addDrawingForMeasureInteraction(geomType) {
    drawingForMeasureInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: sourceForMeasureDrawing,
        type: (geomType),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)',
                width: 2
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 5,
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
                })
            })
        })
    });
    map.addInteraction(drawingForMeasureInteraction);

    createMeasureTooltip();

    var listener;
    drawingForMeasureInteraction.on('drawstart',
        function(evt) {
            sketch = evt.feature;

            var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

            listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
                var geom = evt.target;
                var output;
                if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
                    output = formatArea(geom);
                    tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
                } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
                    output = formatLength(geom);
                    tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
                }
                measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
                measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
            });
        }, this);

    drawingForMeasureInteraction.on('drawend',
        function() {
            measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
            measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
            // unset sketch
            sketch = null;
            // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
            measureTooltipElement = null;
            createMeasureTooltip();
            ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
        }, this);
}

function createMeasureTooltip() {
    if (measureTooltipElement) {
        measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
    }
    measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
    measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
    measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
        element: measureTooltipElement,
        offset: [0, -15],
        positioning: 'bottom-center'
    });
    map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
    $('.tooltip-measure').css('color','red');
}

$(document).on('click', '#measureLine', function () {
    addDrawingForMeasureInteraction('LineString');
});
```

I created a collection (*measureDrawingCollection*) to add the drawn vectors to because I thought it would retain the lines until the collection is cleared, but apparently that does not have any effect.

So, the question is: how can I keep that red line after double-clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As so often when you post a question, you realize shortly afterward what was missing.

In this case I forgot to create a vector layer, which is needed to show the line on the map. Adding this code will make it work:

```
var sourceForMeasureDrawing = new ol.source.Vector();

var measureVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceForMeasureDrawing,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
});

map.addLayer(measureVector);
```